# How to add keys to keyboard layout in Xfce?

Tags: xfce, keyboard-layout

I'm using Linux Lite 3.8 with Xfce.

*TL;DR

Problem: need to type in question marks "?", but can't. How can I add this key to keyboard layout?*

I bought a laptop in the USA that has a regular US-en keyboard. But I need to type special accents (e.g., ó, ò, ö, ô, õ, ç) and the regular keyboard layout doesn't have these keys.

So I went to "Keyboard" => "Layout" tab => set keyboard layout to Brazilian Portuguese. The keyboard model is specified here as "Generic 105-key (Intl) PC". Now I have all the keys I need, **except** the question mark ("?"). No combination of keys I type outputs a question mark. Usually pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>ALT</kbd><kbd>W</kbd> inputs a "?", but this is not working, so when I use the Brazilian Portuguese keyboard layout *I cannot type in question marks*.

Question: How can I add a shortcut or somehow make a combination of keys output a question mark ("?") when using Brazilian Portuguese layout? (just a reminder: I don't know why, but <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>ALT</kbd><kbd>W</kbd> nor <kbd>ALT Gr</kbd><kbd>W</kbd> aren't working)

Thanks!

Comment: I personerly suggest you to use an input method instead of setting X11 keybord layout, which is much more flexible.

Comment: @神秘德里克 Thank you! But how do I do this? Is it something like this?: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Smart_Common_Input_Method . If it is the settings on "Keyboard", I've tried changing those as mentioned in the question

Comment: I use IBus.After installation You'll get a config GUI program in your app menu, you can then add other keyboards and switch between them. But somehow ibus doesn't ship with XDG autostart file, you might need to write your own.

Comment: @神秘德里克 Cool! Thanks a lot, I'll look into that!

Comment: @神秘德里克 If I understood IBus correctly, all it does is switching between different keyboard layouts, but there's no customization option for adding additional keys to the layout. Am I missing something? Should I look for another keyboard layout to install to IBus?